# Install package for COM+

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, com+, component-services

How can I create a msi for COM+ component? Is it possible to create the install package using Visual Studio and have it registered so that it shows up under component services?

I currently have it set up using visual studio and the COM+ file is set up for self registering. However the COM+ application is not showing up under Components Services.

Is there some other method I have to use to install a COM+ application?

Answer (score 3):

We use [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) to create our installers which have COM+ components.

There's some help [here](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson6.php#6.11) for installing COM+ applications. The learning curve is a bit steep at first although the fine control you get over the installation process is well worth it.

Wix projects integrate with Visual Studio just like any other language you may use.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything in the VS installer that would create a Component Services entry; you may be able to find a way by creating a Custom Action.

Comment: What have you tried? I can't find any documentation on how to programmatically create entries in Component Services. This looks pretty tricky.

Comment: I found this article. This was the most help I could get - http://bonemanblog.blogspot.com/2004/08/com-in-msi-of-trials-and-tribulations.html